# Python turtle pen clearing

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm making a game in python using the turtle's pen feature. I have it so that it can display each frame but there is a time after clearing the screen where it updates and shows a pure white screen. Is there any way to clear the screen without updating the picture?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Although I personally don't see people using turtle graphics for animating, here you go.

This code moves a square across the screen.
Basically, instead of "drawing" the object with turtle (which takes time and makes animation look weird), you tell the turtle to wait, and draw the frame all at once.
This way each frame is going to update instantly and make the animation cleaner.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(500,500)
screen.tracer(0)            # tell screen to not show automatically
tom = turtle.Turtle()
tom.speed(0)
tom.width(3)
tom.hideturtle()            # hide donatello, we only want to see the drawing
def draw_square() :
    for side in range(4) :
        tom.forward(100)
        tom.left(90)
tom.penup()
tom.goto(-350, 0)
tom.pendown()
while True :
    tom.clear()
    draw_square()
    screen.update()         # only now show the screen, as one of the frames
    tom.forward(0.02)
```